# Problems starting Suricata on Mac OS X

Tags: security, imagemagick, internet-security, suricata

I am trying to start [Suricata](http://suricata-ids.org) 2.0.7 on Mac OS X but am having issues. Any idea what’s wrong and how to fix it? Here are the errors I am seeing:

```
$ sudo suricata -c /etc/suricata/suricata.yaml -i en2

10/4/2015 -- 20:00:50 - <Notice> - This is Suricata version 2.0.7 RELEASE
/usr/share/file/magic/animation, 712: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `belong' in description `%ld x'
/usr/share/file/magic/animation, 713: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `belong' in description `%ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/animation, 720: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `belong' in description `%ld x'
/usr/share/file/magic/animation, 721: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `belong' in description `%ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/animation, 785: Warning: Current entry does not yet have a description for adding a MIME type
/usr/share/file/magic/animation, 787: Warning: Current entry does not yet have a description for adding a MIME type
/usr/share/file/magic/animation, 789: Warning: Current entry does not yet have a description for adding a MIME type
/usr/share/file/magic/animation, 791: Warning: Current entry does not yet have a description for adding a MIME type
/usr/share/file/magic/animation, 793: Warning: Current entry does not yet have a description for adding a MIME type
/usr/share/file/magic/animation, 795: Warning: Current entry does not yet have a description for adding a MIME type
/usr/share/file/magic/animation, 797: Warning: Current entry does not yet have a description for adding a MIME type
/usr/share/file/magic/animation, 800: Warning: Current entry does not yet have a description for adding a MIME type
/usr/share/file/magic/apple, 202: Warning: Printf format `h' is not valid for type `byte' in description `, version %hhd'
/usr/share/file/magic/apple, 205: Warning: Printf format `h' is not valid for type `beshort' in description `, system %hd'
/usr/share/file/magic/apple, 207: Warning: Printf format `h' is not valid for type `byte' in description `, version %hhd'
/usr/share/file/magic/apple, 210: Warning: Printf format `h' is not valid for type `leshort' in description `, system %hd'
/usr/share/file/magic/archive, 38: Warning: Current entry does not yet have a description for adding a MIME type
/usr/share/file/magic/archive, 251: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `long' in description `, original size: %ld bytes'
/usr/share/file/magic/archive, 816: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `beshort' in description `- version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/att3b, 32: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `beshort' in description `- version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/audio, 107: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `belong' in description `- version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/bflt, 9: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `belong' in description `- version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/cafebabe, 18: Warning: Current entry does not yet have a description for adding a MIME type
/usr/share/file/magic/cafebabe, 35: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `belong' in description `Mach-O universal binary with %ld architectures'
/usr/share/file/magic/cafebabe, 38: Warning: New continuation level 2 is more than one larger than current level 0
/usr/share/file/magic/clarion, 18: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `lelong' in description `, %ld records'
/usr/share/file/magic/clipper, 38: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `short' in description `- version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/clipper, 50: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `short' in description `- version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/dump, 11: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `belong' in description `Volume %ld,'
/usr/share/file/magic/dump, 30: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `belong' in description `Volume %ld,'
/usr/share/file/magic/dump, 49: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `lelong' in description `Volume %ld,'
/usr/share/file/magic/dump, 68: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `lelong' in description `Volume %ld,'
/usr/share/file/magic/dump, 87: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `leshort' in description `Volume %ld,'
/usr/share/file/magic/dump, 99: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `belong' in description `Volume %ld,'
/usr/share/file/magic/dump, 118: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `lelong' in description `Volume %ld,'
/usr/share/file/magic/efi, 15: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `lelong' in description `Universal EFI binary with %ld architectures'
/usr/share/file/magic/encore, 15: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `short' in description `- version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/encore, 20: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `short' in description `- version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/filesystems, 26: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `long' in description `start cyl %ld,'
/usr/share/file/magic/filesystems, 27: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `long' in description `%ld blocks'
/usr/share/file/magic/filesystems, 1024: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `lelong' in description `pending inodes to free %ld,'
/usr/share/file/magic/filesystems, 1044: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `lelong' in description `pending inodes to free %ld,'
/usr/share/file/magic/filesystems, 1084: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `belong' in description `pending inodes to free %ld,'
/usr/share/file/magic/filesystems, 1104: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `belong' in description `pending inodes to free %ld,'
/usr/share/file/magic/filesystems, 1224: Warning: Current entry does not yet have a description for adding a MIME type
/usr/share/file/magic/filesystems, 1244: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `lelong' in description `size %lu'
/usr/share/file/magic/filesystems, 1249: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `lelong' in description `edition %lu,'
/usr/share/file/magic/filesystems, 1250: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `lelong' in description `%lu blocks,'
/usr/share/file/magic/filesystems, 1251: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `lelong' in description `%lu files'
/usr/share/file/magic/filesystems, 1254: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `belong' in description `size %lu'
/usr/share/file/magic/filesystems, 1259: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `belong' in description `edition %lu,'
/usr/share/file/magic/filesystems, 1260: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `belong' in description `%lu blocks,'
/usr/share/file/magic/filesystems, 1261: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `belong' in description `%lu files'
/usr/share/file/magic/games, 9: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `long' in description `%lu skin(s),'
/usr/share/file/magic/games, 10: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `long' in description `(%lu x'
/usr/share/file/magic/games, 11: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `long' in description `%lu),'
/usr/share/file/magic/games, 12: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `long' in description `%lu frame(s),'
/usr/share/file/magic/games, 13: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `long' in description `Frame size %lu bytes,'
/usr/share/file/magic/games, 14: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `long' in description `%lu vertices/frame,'
/usr/share/file/magic/games, 15: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `long' in description `%lu texture coordinates,'
/usr/share/file/magic/games, 16: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `long' in description `%lu triangles/frame'
/usr/share/file/magic/games, 148: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `belong' in description `version %lu'
/usr/share/file/magic/gimp, 18: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `belong' in description `%lu x'
/usr/share/file/magic/gimp, 19: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `belong' in description `%lu,'
/usr/share/file/magic/gnome-keyring, 11: Warning: Printf format `h' is not valid for type `byte' in description `, crypto type %hhu (unknown)'
/usr/share/file/magic/gnome-keyring, 13: Warning: Printf format `h' is not valid for type `byte' in description `, hash type %hhu (unknown)'
/usr/share/file/magic/gnu, 16: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `belong' in description `, version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/hp, 44: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `beshort' in description `- version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/hp, 47: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `beshort' in description `- version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/hp, 131: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `long' in description `- version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/hp, 134: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `long' in description `- version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/hp, 137: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `long' in description `- version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/hp, 141: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `beshort' in description `- version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/hp, 148: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `beshort' in description `- version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/hp, 155: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `beshort' in description `- version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/hp, 162: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `beshort' in description `- version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/hp, 169: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `beshort' in description `- version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/hp, 173: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `beshort' in description `- version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/hp, 177: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `beshort' in description `- version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/hp, 182: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `beshort' in description `- version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/hp, 195: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `byte' in description `- version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/ibm370, 39: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `belong' in description `- version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/ibm370, 42: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `belong' in description `- version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/ibm370, 45: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `belong' in description `- version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/ibm370, 48: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `belong' in description `- version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/images, 22: Warning: Printf format `h' is not valid for type `leshort' in description `%hd x'
/usr/share/file/magic/images, 23: Warning: Printf format `h' is not valid for type `leshort' in description `%hd'
/usr/share/file/magic/images, 26: Warning: Printf format `h' is not valid for type `leshort' in description `%hd x'
/usr/share/file/magic/images, 27: Warning: Printf format `h' is not valid for type `leshort' in description `%hd'
/usr/share/file/magic/images, 30: Warning: Printf format `h' is not valid for type `leshort' in description `%hd x'
/usr/share/file/magic/images, 31: Warning: Printf format `h' is not valid for type `leshort' in description `%hd'
/usr/share/file/magic/images, 82: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `belong' in description `, %ld x'
/usr/share/file/magic/images, 83: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `belong' in description `%ld,'
/usr/share/file/magic/images, 118: Warning: Printf format `h' is not valid for type `leshort' in description `%hd x'
/usr/share/file/magic/images, 119: Warning: Printf format `h' is not valid for type `leshort' in description `%hd'
/usr/share/file/magic/images, 388: Warning: Printf format `h' is not valid for type `leshort' in description `bounding box [%hd,'
/usr/share/file/magic/images, 389: Warning: Printf format `h' is not valid for type `leshort' in description `%hd] -'
/usr/share/file/magic/images, 390: Warning: Printf format `h' is not valid for type `leshort' in description `[%hd,'
/usr/share/file/magic/images, 391: Warning: Printf format `h' is not valid for type `leshort' in description `%hd],'
/usr/share/file/magic/images, 393: Warning: Printf format `h' is not valid for type `byte' in description `%hhd-bit'
/usr/share/file/magic/images, 399: Warning: Printf format `h' is not valid for type `leshort' in description `%hd x'
/usr/share/file/magic/images, 400: Warning: Printf format `h' is not valid for type `leshort' in description `%hd dpi,'
/usr/share/file/magic/images, 524: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `lelong' in description `volume %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/images, 547: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `belong' in description `, %ld x'
/usr/share/file/magic/images, 548: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `belong' in description `%ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/images, 555: Warning: Printf format `h' is not valid for type `leshort' in description `%hd x'
/usr/share/file/magic/images, 556: Warning: Printf format `h' is not valid for type `leshort' in description `%hd,'
/usr/share/file/magic/images, 558: Warning: Printf format `h' is not valid for type `leshort' in description `%hd images in file'
/usr/share/file/magic/intel, 36: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `leshort' in description `- version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/karma, 9: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `belong' in description `%lu'
/usr/share/file/magic/linux, 82: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `leshort' in description `- version %ld.'
/usr/share/file/magic/mach, 23: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `lelong' in description `filetype=%ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/mach, 25: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `lelong' in description `architecture=%ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/mach, 47: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `lelong' in description `architecture=%ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/mach, 63: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `belong' in description `filetype=%ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/mach, 65: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `belong' in description `architecture=%ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/mach, 92: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `belong' in description `architecture=%ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/maple, 36: Warning: New continuation level 3 is more than one larger than current level 1
/usr/share/file/magic/mips, 20: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `byte' in description `- version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/mips, 23: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `byte' in description `- version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/mips, 25: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `byte' in description `- version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/mips, 27: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `byte' in description `- version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/mips, 29: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `belong' in description `- version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/mips, 37: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `byte' in description `- version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/mips, 38: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `byte' in description `.%ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/mips, 47: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `byte' in description `.%ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/mips, 56: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `byte' in description `.%ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/mips, 64: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `byte' in description `- version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/mips, 65: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `byte' in description `.%ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/mips, 75: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `byte' in description `- version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/mips, 76: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `byte' in description `.%ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/mips, 84: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `byte' in description `- version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/mips, 85: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `byte' in description `.%ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/mips, 93: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `byte' in description `- version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/mips, 94: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `byte' in description `.%ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/mips, 102: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `byte' in description `- version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/mips, 103: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `byte' in description `.%ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/mips, 113: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `byte' in description `- version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/mips, 114: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `byte' in description `.%ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/mips, 122: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `byte' in description `- version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/mips, 123: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `byte' in description `.%ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/mips, 131: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `byte' in description `- version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/mips, 132: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `byte' in description `.%ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/mips, 140: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `byte' in description `- version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/mips, 141: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `byte' in description `.%ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/mips, 163: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `byte' in description `.%ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/motorola, 43: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `belong' in description `(txt=%ld,'
/usr/share/file/magic/motorola, 44: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `belong' in description `dat=%ld,'
/usr/share/file/magic/motorola, 45: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `belong' in description `bss=%ld,'
/usr/share/file/magic/motorola, 46: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `belong' in description `sym=%ld)'
/usr/share/file/magic/motorola, 48: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `belong' in description `(txt=%ld,'
/usr/share/file/magic/motorola, 49: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `belong' in description `dat=%ld,'
/usr/share/file/magic/motorola, 50: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `belong' in description `bss=%ld,'
/usr/share/file/magic/motorola, 51: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `belong' in description `sym=%ld)'
/usr/share/file/magic/motorola, 55: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `belong' in description `text len %lu,'
/usr/share/file/magic/motorola, 56: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `belong' in description `data len %lu,'
/usr/share/file/magic/motorola, 57: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `belong' in description `BSS len %lu,'
/usr/share/file/magic/motorola, 58: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `belong' in description `symboltab len %lu,'
/usr/share/file/magic/motorola, 63: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `belong' in description `flags: 0x%lX,'
/usr/share/file/magic/motorola, 71: Warning: Printf format `0' is not valid for type `beshort' in description `(version %04lx)'
/usr/share/file/magic/msdos, 54: Warning: Current entry does not yet have a description for adding a MIME type
/usr/share/file/magic/msdos, 545: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `lelong' in description `(%ld records)'
/usr/share/file/magic/msdos, 548: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `lelong' in description `(%ld records)'
/usr/share/file/magic/msdos, 650: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `belong' in description `, Backing File( Offset: %lu'
/usr/share/file/magic/msdos, 704: Warning: Printf format `h' is not valid for type `lelong' in description `%hd x'
/usr/share/file/magic/msdos, 705: Warning: Printf format `h' is not valid for type `lelong' in description `%hd,'
/usr/share/file/magic/ncr, 14: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `beshort' in description `- version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/ncr, 19: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `beshort' in description `- version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/ncr, 24: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `beshort' in description `- version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/ncr, 29: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `beshort' in description `- version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/ncr, 34: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `beshort' in description `- version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/ncr, 42: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `beshort' in description `- version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/ncr, 49: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `beshort' in description `- version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/pdp, 13: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `byte' in description `- version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/pdp, 20: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `byte' in description `- version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/pdp, 24: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `byte' in description `- version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/riff, 61: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `lelong' in description `, %lu x'
/usr/share/file/magic/riff, 62: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `lelong' in description `%lu,'
/usr/share/file/magic/rpm, 30: Warning: New continuation level 3 is more than one larger than current level 1
/usr/share/file/magic/sequent, 10: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `lelong' in description `version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/sequent, 13: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `lelong' in description `version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/sequent, 16: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `lelong' in description `version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/sequent, 19: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `lelong' in description `version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/sequent, 26: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `lelong' in description `version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/sequent, 29: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `lelong' in description `version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/sequent, 32: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `lelong' in description `version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/sequent, 35: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `lelong' in description `version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/sgi, 22: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `belong' in description `log volume #%ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/sharc, 22: Warning: Printf format `h' is not valid for type `leshort' in description `, %hd sections'
/usr/share/file/magic/sun, 102: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `belong' in description `- version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/ti-8x, 225: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `lelong' in description `size: %ld bytes'
/usr/share/file/magic/unknown, 23: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `byte' in description `- version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/unknown, 26: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `byte' in description `- version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/unknown, 29: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `byte' in description `- version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/unknown, 32: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `byte' in description `- version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/varied.out, 29: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `long' in description `- version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/vax, 32: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `leshort' in description `- version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/vax, 35: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `leshort' in description `- version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/vorbis, 59: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `lelong' in description `UNKNOWN VERSION %lu,'
/usr/share/file/magic/vorbis, 65: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `lelong' in description `%lu Hz'
/usr/share/file/magic/vorbis, 75: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `lelong' in description `<%lu'
/usr/share/file/magic/vorbis, 77: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `lelong' in description `~%lu'
/usr/share/file/magic/vorbis, 81: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `lelong' in description `>%lu'
/usr/share/file/magic/windows, 39: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `lelong' in description `, %ld pages'
/usr/share/file/magic/xilinx, 35: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `belong' in description `- data length 0x%lx'
/usr/share/file/magic/xwindows, 21: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `long' in description `- version %ld'
/usr/share/file/magic/xwindows, 22: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `long' in description `- [%ld -'
/usr/share/file/magic/xwindows, 23: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `long' in description `%ldx'
/usr/share/file/magic/xwindows, 24: Warning: Printf format `l' is not valid for type `long' in description `%ldx'
/usr/share/file/magic/xwindows, 34: Warning: Printf format `h' is not valid for type `leshort' in description `version %hd'
/usr/share/file/magic/xwindows, 35: Warning: Printf format `h' is not valid for type `leshort' in description `.%hd'
10/4/2015 -- 20:00:51 - <Error> - [ERRCODE: SC_ERR_MAGIC_LOAD(197)] - magic_load failed: File 5.22 supports only version 12 magic files. `/usr/share/file/magic.mgc' is version 7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I thought that was a libmagic bug. I've sent an email to homebrew developers and they fixed versions of `suricata` and `libmagic`. But the issue still appeared. So one of them pointed me in right direction:

in `suricata.yaml` the correct path to magic-file should be set up. 
If the libmagic dependancy was installed from homebrew:

`magic-file: /usr/local/opt/libmagic/share/misc/magic`

That's it! Now it works!

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug in either `binwalk` or `libmagic`. Check what version of those packages you have installed. You may need to downgrade them.

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=754317

Comment: Thanx for reply. I have no binwalk installed. libmagic version is stable 5.22 from Homebrew. I have no idea which version doesn't have this bug and which one should I use to be able to run Suricata. Please help.